# Conditional Formatting through code

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hello  I am parsing some data from other website using this Request :

```
   Public Function giveMeValue(ByVal link As Variant) As Variant

Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
   .Open "GET", link, False
   .send
   htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

If Not htm.getelementbyId("JS_topStoreCount") Is Nothing Then

   giveMeValue = htm.getelementbyId("JS_topStoreCount").innerText

Else
    giveMeValue = "0"

End If

htm.Close
Set htm = Nothing

End Function
```

with the function on the cell   `=giveMeValue(A1)` now I need to apply some formatting condition to copied value but I am unable to do it with the excel conditional formatting

The active cell "B" column

1. Less than 10 Red
2. Between 10 and 15 Yellow
3. More than 15 Green

Aall the cell not returning any number should be blank , please consider the  `=giveMeValue(A1)` return as string

Comment: I recognize this code snippet :) Have you tried to declare the function `As Integer` rather than `As String`, if you know that the return would always be convertible to an `Integer`? I guess the problem is that conditional formatting doesn't recognize the number because it's returned as a string, as you correctly say.

Comment: ...and you can also resort to `=VALUE(...)` in a conditional format rule.

Comment: Matteo of course you recognize it  :-) is your and all credits goes to you of course , I am not able to   do it by myself ,   the return will always be integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers (and *Long* integers) cannot by nature contain fractional (aka *decimal*) portions of a number. I strongly suspect that this is an important factor but any details that would clear this up are missing from your question.

Remove the `As String` in the function declaration. This effectively changes it to the default of `As Variant`.  The only other operation would be to change one code line to,

`giveMeValue = CDbl(.innerText)`

This should return a numerical value whether there is a decimal involved or not. The function will return an error if text that cannot be converted to a number is retrieved from the scrape.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped , sometimes the "JS_topStoreCount" element doesn't exist on the page  so the formula return as #VALUE!  how can I return as "0" instead?

Comment: @user2482756 - That comment seems to contradict your earlier statement that *"the return will ALWAYS be integer"*. It seems a fool's errand to keep trying to compensate for conditions that you are unwilling to disclose.

Comment: @user2482756 - How about `=IFERROR(giveMeValue(A1), 0)` ?

Comment: no doesn't seems to be working , I found the work around  for the "0" matter but now still have the previous problem with the color formatting , I updated  the post   with the new code

Comment: I solve it with macro as follow :

`'Dim color As Integer

 For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("B1:F65536")

    If IsEmpty(cell) Then GoTo nextcell:
    If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo nextcell:

    If cell.Value > 14 Then
      color = 4
    ElseIf cell.Value < 8 Then color = 3
    Else: color = 6
    End If
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = color
nextcell:
  Next cell

End Sub'`

Comment: Any code advice  for button to update all the link " GiveMeValue(A1) "?

Comment: @user2482756 - I am glad to hear you got sorted out. If adding `Application.Volatile` as a new first line of the *giveMeValue* code is insufficient (or too intensive processing-wise), I would suggest taking this related topic to a new question with a fresh posting of your working code as it is now. Should be a good opportunity to address the new issue and exercise your new question writing skills.